# CakePHP. Login not Working on Deploy Sever

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have my system working fine on my local server, and it performs the Login perfectly. The problem is that when I upload it to my hosting, I keep getting the Wrong Password Message, as if couldn't create the sessio and I have no idea why. My tmp is writable, I checked with sql_dump the username and password in the query and they are ok, the password is hashed correctly.

I did change something in the configuration of cake to use the tmp folder to store sessions. I though maybe that would be the problem, but noup. it's still not working.

Any idea of what it going on?

Comment: Have you checked apache access and error logs

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the database connection settings are incorrect for the live environment.

Open `app/config/database.php` and check `class DATABASE_CONFIG`

There should be a db config array in there for each environment. Also, the comments in the code above this class are worth a read.